# How to cabalize haskell packages with multiple authors

Tags: haskell, cabal

All the tutorials and examples of how to cabalize a Haskell package assume the package has a single author (as well as a single maintainer).  How to I properly credit multiple Authors in a .cabal file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best practice, but I just use a comma separated list of names.

```
Author:              John Doe, Tikhon Jelvis
```

You could also include email addresses:

```
Author:              John Doe <john.doe@example.com>, Tikhon Jelvis <tikhon@berkeley.edu>
```

Comment: I eventually discovered a package on hackage which did just that.  It would be really nice if this was properly documented.

Comment: Yeah, I also found the lack of documentation depressing. But since I'm too lazy to care about correctness too much, I just made stuff up as I went along :P.